Установка парсера на Fastpanel
У меня есть парсер на Python, который работает по API с Google таблицами. Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли и если можно, то как этот парсер загрузить и запустить на хостинге управляемом Fastpanel?


Подключиться к серверу по SFTP через FileZilla, указать Host: IP адресс сервера, Username: fastuser, Password: ваш пароль, Port: 22
Перенести файлы на сервер
Подключиться через SSH, настроить окружение
В Fastpanel создать Cron

